# PHP Code Not Executing on Form Submission

Tags: php, html, apache, google-cloud-platform

**Problem:**

I have created a simple web server with apache hosted by google cloud services and I am having a hard time figuring out how to get my PHP code to execute when a form has been submitted.

---

**Objective:**

I want the user to be able to input some information into a form and have it sent to the server. From there the server will run some PHP code and write the information to a file in the same directory.

---

**How it works now:**

When I submit the form instead of executing the action it just opens up the file as a text document in the browser.

[image: Redirected after form submission]

---

**Form from Main.html**

```
<form action="processForm.php" method="POST">
      Spotify URI: <input type="text" name="uri">
      <br/>
      Description: <input type="text" name="description">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

**processForm.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uri']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {
    $data = $_POST['uri'] . '-' . $_POST['description'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('data.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```

---

I don't believe it is an issue with PHP being installed improperly. When I run `php -v` it echoes

`PHP 5.6.29-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Dec 13 2016 16:02:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies`

---

Comment: how are you using this, as `http://localhost` or as `file:///` directly into your browser?

Comment: http://104.198.196.248/Main.html

Comment: ok I deleted my comment about the `.html` thing. Well that is most bizarre. Does `<?php echo "Hello world";` work in a php file?

Comment: Similar to @Fred's question: can you get `phpinfo()` to work?

Comment: <?php echo "Hello world"; does not work

Comment: Where should I type phpinfo()

Comment: `<?php phpinfo();` and create a `.php` file for it. If that doesn't do anything, you will need to contact Google support.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It still loads it as a text file.

Comment: You may have both PHP and Apache server installed on your system, but the server will not interpret the PHP code. There is some extra settings for the Apache to be able to run PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem.  I got phpinfo() working but form submission just gave the PHP in plain text, not executing.  Funk Forty Niner had the right idea.  From file:///DocumentRoot/Main.html (where DocumentRoot is whatever it is on your machine), the PHP doesn't execute.  But from localhost/Main.html, it does.  It's exactly the same file, but the browser treats the form differently.